# MySQL Select Data from multiple tables based on one id

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 2 tables that look like this:

```
content
id    name
1     Cool Stuff
2     Even Better stuff
```

--

```
contentFields
id     content     label       value
5      1           Rating      Spectacular
6      1           Info        Top Notch
7      2           Rating      Poor
```

As you can see the `content` column of the `contentFields` table coincides with the `id` column of the `content` table.

I want to write a query that grabs all of the content and stores the applicable content fields with the right content, so that it comes out to this:

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Cool Stuff',
  contentFields: [
     {label: 'Rating', value: 'Spectacular'},
     {label: 'Info', value: 'Top Notch'}
  ]
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Even Better Stuff',
  contentFields: [
      {label: 'Rating', value: 'Poor'}
  ]
 }
]
```

I tried an inner join like this:

`SELECT * FROM content INNER JOIN contentFields ON content.id = contentFields.content GROUP BY content.id`

But that didn't do it.

*Note: I know that I could do this with 2 seperate queries, but I want to find out how to do it in one as that will dramatically improve performance.

Comment: What does the result of your query look like? Because you're asking for JSON result, which I'm assuming you're building from a MySQL result, using what language? How do you transform it?

Comment: It's in NodeJS MySQL which parses the result as JSON by default

Comment: Do you have any requirements what the MySQL results should look like, in order for your parser to work?

Comment: No it should work with anything

Comment: Get rid of your group by

Comment: I got rid of the group by and it creates a huge list of data for each content fields (it doesn't group them into one data object)

Comment: Show us the result from MySQL you would like to get

Comment: The table version of the JSON

Comment: It would essentially be a table in a table.  I also tried `SELECT * FROM content (SELECT * FROM contentFields WHERE content=id) AS contentFields`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not directly possible with SQL only.

As you have already stated yourself, you are looking for a table within a table. But MySQL does not know about such concepts, and as far as I know, other databases also don't. A result set is always like a table; every row of the result set has the same structure.

So either you let your `GROUP BY content.id` in place; then, for every row in the result set, MySQL will select a *random* row from the joined table which fits to that row's `content.id` (you even can't rely on that it is the same row every time).

Or you remove the `GROUP BY`; then you will get every row from the joined table, but that is not what you want as well.

When performance is an issue, I would probably choose the second option, adding `ORDER BY content.id`, and generate the JSON myself. You could do so by looping through the result set and begin a new JSON block every time the `content.id` changes.

**Disclaimer** The following is pure speculation.

I don't know anything about node.js and how it transforms result sets into JSON. But I strongly assume that you can configure its behavior; otherwise, it actually would not be of any use in most cases. So there must be a method to tell it how it should group the rows from a result set.

If I am right, you would first have to tell node.js how to group the result set and then let it process the rows from the second option above (i.e. without the `GROUP BY`).